# How to integrate a Kafka consumer with a long running process, like a file download?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka consumers need to be polled at regular intervals. This can lead to problems when writing batch processing systems where Kafka is being used as a notification layer to trigger the running and coordination of jobs.

For example, I am working with a system that downloads a large file from AWS. This takes about a minute to complete, which exceeds the default consumer maximum poll time, causing it to be disconnected from the consumer group by the Kafka system.

This seems like a pretty standard problem, so I'm sure there is a standard architecture for solving the problem. I'm just not sure what that is. I have a few possible ideas.

Here's some example code to clarify the issue:

```py
# Taken from part of a consumer loop

message = consumer.poll(consumer_poll_timeout)

if message is not None:
    topic_partition_assignment = consumer.assignment()
    consumer.pause(topic_partition_assignment)

    # this function takes a long time to complete
    run_download_and_notify(producer)

    consumer.resume(topic_partition_assignment)
    consumer.commit()
```

What the code does:

- It waits for a "notification" from a Kafka topic to come in
- The notification triggers the process to start the process of downloading a file
- When the file is downloaded, another notification is sent to another topic to kick off the next process in the chain

My theory was that calling `consumer.pause` might "pause" the consumer and temporarily remove the requirement to continue polling it. I was wrong, and I didn't really expect this to work. Polling is required to send heartbeat messages to the broker to prevent a consumer from being kicked out of a consumer group. Pausing a consumer just allows you to continue polling without any data being returned.

Given that this doesn't work, here's a couple of ideas:

- Dispatch the download process as its own thread. When done, join the thread again. It isn't obvious to me that this will work. We need some way of checking if a thread is finished working before trying to join it. Otherwise, we have the same issue, waiting a long period of time for a join.
- Poll the consumer from another thread. It's a bit of a "backwards" mental model but will probably work. The downloader thread will remain the "master" thread.
- Dispatch a separate process to do the downloading
- Call unsubscribe on the consumer, then re-subscribe it later. The issue here is we cannot commit the records which have been read because we do not know that the download process will complete successfully. If we unsubscribe, we will end up reading those records again, which creates a problem of having to implement some complex logic to perform de-duplication. It really doesn't seem like the way forward.

Comment: "Pausing allows you to continue polling without data returned" + "Polling is required to send heartbeats" - if both are true, pausing should work

Comment: @OneCricketeer to clarify, because I am not sure that it was clear, I aim to write some code which avoids the need to continue to poll the consumer, but I am not sure if it is possible. I'm not totally sure if I interpret your comment correctly but it sounds like you also think this cannot be done? (And therefore perhaps a threading approach is required?)

Comment: I've not seen any different implementations than what is shown. Are you saying it doesn't work since the download step is blocking the next poll call? In that case, starting another thread seems like the solution

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes - if the poll timeout is left at the default (which I think these days is something like 30 seconds) a long running download (which in this case takes about 10 minutes to complete) will cause the consumer to be ejected from the consumer group. Perhaps handling it with a thread is indeed the only solution.